# Verify linear independence of the following sets of vectors:

Tags: linear-algebra

Verify linear independence of the following sets of vectors:
$\{\sin 2x, \cos 2x, \cos^2 x\}$ in R^R over $\Bbb R$,

Comment: You need to format the question a little better. If I read correctly, your set above has two elements, and linear independence can be demonstrated by evaluating at $x=0$ and $x={\pi \over 2}$.

Comment: @copper.hat I am not sure but maybe the set is $\{ \sin 2x, \cos 2x, \cos^2 x\}.$

Comment: yes my bad its {sin2x,cos2x,cos^2 x}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a\sin (2x)+b\cos (2x)+c\cos^2x=0$$

For $x=0$ then

$$b+c=0$$

For $x=\pi/2$ then

$$-b=0$$

so $b=c=0$ and then

$$a\sin (2x)=0$$

Take $x=\pi/4$ and get $a=0$.